# SQL: Output rows for which one column in the same table is different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I haven't really found a way to explain this correctly with words, so here is an example:

```
| Product number | Price Period | Price |
-----------------------------------------
| 0001           | 1            | 200   |
-----------------------------------------
| 0001           | 2            | 200   |
-----------------------------------------
| 0002           | 1            | 110   |
-----------------------------------------
| 0002           | 2            | 115   |
-----------------------------------------
```

So there are multiple prices for the same product in the same table. The primary key is composited of Product Number and Price Period.

How can I give out the products where the price has changed since the last period? The only way I can come up with right now would be an inner join on a subselect.

Comment: And what is the problem with the query you came up with?

Comment: Expected results please.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `lag()` function

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=41499ac3860018be8296fc7d66ab3f48)**

```
 select * from 
 (
 select productnumber,priceperiod,price,
 lag(price,1) over(partition by productnumber order by priceperiod) as changedprice 
 from cte
 )A where price<>changedprice and changedprice is not null
```

OUTPUT:

```
productnumber   priceperiod   price   changedprice
0002               2           115     110
```

Comment: You can safely remove "and changedprice is not null"

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by simpler self join also. I assume this is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(ProductNumber int, PricePeriod int, Price int);

INSERT INTO Product
    (ProductNumber, PricePeriod, Price)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 200),
    (1, 2, 200),
    (2, 1, 110),
    (2, 2, 115);
```

And query should be

```
select A.ProductNumber, A.PricePeriod, A.Price, B.PricePeriod, B.Price
FROM Product A
JOIN Product B
ON A.ProductNumber = B.ProductNumber
AND A.PricePeriod < B.PricePeriod
AND A.Price != B.Price;
```

In this query, there is a condition "A.PricePeriod < B.PricePeriod" that will only show older Price period and "A.Price != B.Price" will eliminate all rows with same prices

Comment: But with more than one price periodes this will fail... If I get this correctly, the OP needs a change from one periode to the next. But this is not absolutely clear. Might be that the query is always limited to a periode and its predecessor... If periodes are gap-less you might use `AND A.PricePeriod=B.PricePeriod+1`...

Comment: May be you are right but it not clear in either ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
select po.Product from products po inner join
    (
    select pr.product,pr.Period,pr.Price from products pr inner join
        (
        select product,max(period)as [period] from products
        group by product
        ) mx on mx.Product = pr.Product and mx.period = pr.Period
    ) mxx on mxx.Product = po.Product 
and po.Period = mxx.Period-1
and mxx.Price <> po.Price
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I give out the products where the price has changed **since the last period**?

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([Product number] varchar(20), [Price Period] int, [Price] int);

INSERT INTO T
    ([Product number], [Price Period], [Price])
VALUES
    ('0001', 1, 100),
    ('0001', 2, 200),
    ('0001', 3, 200),
    ('0002', 1, 110),
    ('0002', 2, 115);

SELECT [Product number],
       [Price Period],
       [Price]
FROM
(
SELECT [Product number],
       [Price Period],
       [Price],
       [Price] - LAG([Price])OVER(PARTITION BY [Product number] ORDER BY [Product number]) Changes,
       (SELECT MAX([Price period]) FROM T WHERE [Product number] = TT.[Product number]) N
FROM T TT
) TBL
WHERE Changes > 0
      AND
      [Price Period] = N;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=18e7f51fdfc4e37a588e49f14cf28131)**